# Approach for identity based query filter .NET

Tags: c#, .net, identity, clean-architecture

I am working on a .NET WebApi application built around a clean architecture design.

In the higher layer of the solution, in the WebApi project, where the controllers sit, I have a static helper class with a method that checks if the current user is present in a certain active directory group.
**The username is retrieved from the request's headers**

```cs
public static bool IsUserInGroup(string userName, string userGroup)
{
    // blablabla

    return isUserInGroup;
}
```

Lower, in the application layer, I'm using my repository class to retrieve some records.

```cs
public List<MyObjectDto> GetValuation(int valuationId)
{
    // checkUserGroup?
    // filterExpression based on AD group

    var myObjectList = _repository.Get(filterExpression, includesProperties);

    return myObjectList;
}
```

I intend to filter out records based on the user's group and I was thinking which approach is better for this situation.

1. Should I change the class into a service, put the interface in the Application layer, and implement it higher?
2. Should I simply check the user's group in the controller and pass the result down?
3. Should I move the helper class to the application layer? (I would guess not as identity-related logic should not be there)
4. Other suggested approach

New Edit:
[image]

Comment: Where is the "source of data" for the user to user-group mappings?  an active-directory ?  a database?

Comment: It's active directory, I'm using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, context being active directory domain services.

Comment: Ok, so in that case I would write an IUserGroupDomainDataLayer and have a concrete called ActiveDirectoryUserGroupDomainDataLayer.  While it is NOT a RDBMS datastore, Active-Directory is a data-store, just a somewhat unique one.  You should use it (code for it) as a data-store.  Make this domain-data-layer object "dumb",  and call it to use in your business logic layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let me show a subtle difference between a data-layer and a business-logic layer.

A requirement comes in, "I need Active Employees".

This is typical code:

```
interface IEmployeeDomainData
    public ICollection<Employee> GetActiveEmployees();

interface IEmployeeManagerBusinessLogic
    public ICollection<Employee> GetActiveEmployees();
```

The above is what I call a "mimic".

But the mimic is short sighted.

Let me explain:

I strongly suggest to NOT do the above...but to make the (domain) data layer...."more reusable, more generic in nature".

DomainDataLayer

```
IEmployeeDomainData

    Collection<Employee> GetActiveEmployees()  <<< NO !!!!!!!  HARD CODE BUSINESS RULE IN DOMAIN DATA LAYER.  DO NOT HARD CODE RULES IN THE DomainDataLayer.

    Better Option:

     Collection​<Employee> GetEmployeesByEmpStatus(int empStatusValue)  

    Even Better Option:

     Collection​<Employee> GetEmployeesByEmpStatuses(ICollection<int> empStatusValues)
```

Why?
In the future, you get a new requirement.

```
"Please provide a collection of Terminated Employees"

This is Ok for business logic layer ->             Collection<Employee> GetTerminatedEmployees()

Now, because you did NOT hard code your business logic rule in the DomainDataLayer, you can just REUSE and EXISTING DomainDataLayer method.

Below are the (now two) Business Logic Layer methods:


  Collection<Employee> GetActiveEmployees()​
  {
         return this.injectedEmpDomainDataLayer.GetEmployeesByEmpStatus​( activeEmpStatusSingleSourceOfTruthValue );
  }


     
  Collection<Employee> GetTerminatedEmployees()​
  {
         return this.injectedEmpDomainDataLayer.GetEmployeesByEmpStatus( terminatedEmpStatusSingleSourceOfTruthValue );
  }
```

That is a subtle but important difference between the 2 layers.
They are not just "mimics" of each other.

....

Then you also need to consider "what is the cost to access a ROW of data in from the datastore (typically RDBMS database) vs getting a single column of a single row.

In your case, (for your User check) I would probably start with getting a ROW of a "User" in the (domain) datalayer, using

string userName, string userGroup

parameters.

You don't show your object model.  Does User have one UserGroup or many UserGroups (1:N, M:N, etc).

then based on that return of a User, make decisions about it in the business logic layer.  Based on your object model, you may choose to .Include(user => user.UserGroup (aka, add in navigation properties)

What I am trying to suggest is that .. there probably isn't much different in getting 1 ROW of a table from the database...versus getting 1 column of one row...unless the row DDL has many many columns or has a large column (BLOB/TEXT or something like that).  So the developer should consider maintenance/reuse vs a super optimized sql command (that EntityFramework or Dapper or your-own-custom-code) executes.  I am usually ok with getting a single row.

And like my "GetTerminatedEmployees" example.. you have something you can possible reuse in the future that does not put the business rules in the (domain) datalayer.

Other notes.

Your WebApi layer is NOT your business logic layer.

Here  is a "measuring stick".  What if you wanted to expose your business logic as gRpc?  or (old school) WCF?

You should only have code that deals with WebApi in the WebApi layer.
Mainly, "collect input parameters"  .. push to the business logic layer .. return outgoing values as Http friendly.  Deal with Http-Status codes (from EXCEPTIONS in your business logic layer).

When gRPC is coded... it should be much REUSE of the business logic layer...with the same "collect input parameters"  .. push to the business logic layer .. return outgoing values as gRPC friendly.  Deal with gRPC-Status codes (from EXCEPTIONS in your business logic layer).

While developers say they "understand what the business logic layer" is for.....it is a constant struggle to not let business logic "slip into the webapi/rest layer" and "let it slip into the (domain) data layer".

Very important ANTI PATTERN:
(using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/exception-throwing )

Your BusinessLogic (and down) layers should NOT HAVE any "http-status-codes, http-context" objects/values references.
Your WebApi code uses/codes-up http-status-codes, http-context, etc...but NOTHING "below" this layer should have it.
I cannot tell you the number of codes bases I've encountered that made http-status-codes a (very poor) substitute for "exeptions/exception-stacktraces".  Again, see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/exception-throwing and

> ❌ DO NOT return error codes.
>
> Exceptions are the primary means of reporting errors in frameworks.
>
> ✔️ DO report execution failures by throwing exceptions.

As I am constantly reminding the jr developers on the team:

> In which layer does the business logic go?
>
> (It is NOT a trick question): It goes in  the business logic layer.

But that's the thing.  It goes in the business logic layer.
(Not "up" to the WebApi-Rest layer, not "down" into the (domain)data layer.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for all the insights. I think the most valuable part for me by far "You should only have code that deals with WebApi in the WebApi layer. Mainly, "collect input parameters" .. push to the business logic layer .. return outgoing values as Http friendly." Still, I might have messed up my explanation a bit in the post. I have added a new image that shows my scenario.

Comment: My number one concern was to NOT add any kind of logic in the controllers, to keep them as simple as possible. I wanted to make the "role" check of the user in the application layer where I also build my query expression to avoid adding anything in the controllers. Also, my requirement sounds like that : "If the user is part of the group SUPERUSER from active directory return all records, else only return data from the last 3 months"

Answer (score 0):

There should be :-

1. Controller
2. Service layer
3. Repository layer

Put your business logic in service layer .
Communicate from controller to service layer by interface and also from service layer to repository layer through interface.

Abstraction be there in there in high level and low level.

It will also help if in future major change in class.

Business logic should be in service layer and all the data acces in repository layer it will also help in future to check and lot.

Comment: outside of using "java spring'ish names" (or maybe some other language typical names)... why was this down-voted?